How to Extend List<T> in Dart?
How to make a custom List constructor in Dart? My attempt was to extend a List  but it seems to not work.

The class 'FooList' can't extend 'List' because 'List' only has
factory constructors (no generative constructors), and 'FooList' has
at least one generative constructor

Here is the context:
typedef JsonMap = Map<String, dynamic>;

typedef JsonList = List<JsonMap>;

class Foo {
  final String foo;

  Foo(this.foo);

  factory Foo.fromJson(JsonMap json) {
    return Foo(json['foo']);
  }

  JsonMap toJson() {
    return {'foo': foo};
  }
}

My goal is to fromJson parse a list of JsonMap
typedef FooList = List<Foo>;
void main() {
  final jsonList = [
    {'foo': 'bar'},
    {'foo': 'baz'},
  ];

  final foos = jsonList.map((e) => Foo.fromJson(e)).toList(); // I don't like this, too verbose

  print(foosBetter);
}

In traditional Dart development, the above is ok, but it seems to verbose. Something like this will be ideal.
 final foosBetter = FooList.from(jsonList); // I like this better, but this is obviously not working
So my attempt was instead of declaring FooList as a simple alias:
abstract class FooList extends List<Foo> {
  FooList.from(List<JsonMap> jsonList) {
    addAll(jsonList.map((e) => Foo.fromJson(e)));
  }
}

Which leads to the error quoted above.

List in dart is an interface so you can't just extend it.
You can either extend an implementation of List such as DelegatingList from package collection.
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

abstract class FooList extends DelegatingList<Foo> {
  FooList.from(List<JsonMap> jsonList)
      : super(jsonList.map(Foo.fromJson).toList());
}


Or extend from ListBase.
import 'dart:collection';

abstract class FooList extends ListBase<Foo> {
  FooList.from(List<JsonMap> jsonList) {
    addAll(jsonList.map(Foo.fromJson));
  }
}

Or you can create an extension type on a List.
extension type FooList(List<Foo> list) implements List<Foo> {
  FooList.from(List<JsonMap> jsonList)
      : this(jsonList.map(Foo.fromJson).toList());
}

Or you can implement the List interface, but that would require providing definitions for all List methods.

Which version Dart supports extension type ?

I use 3.3.1, my Android studio IDE does not seem to know about it

Since 3.3: https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-3-3-325bf2bf6c13

does your pubspece.yaml set sdk to at least 3.3 minimum? sdk: '>=3.3.0 <4.0.0'

Oh I got it , I changed pubsec to environment:
sdk: ^3.3.0

Thanks a lot!  Dart's new features are cool

Wow, I saw your edit there! I don't think I ever used `dart:collection'
